# How can I see the attr of subvolume?

Tags: btrfs

```
btrfs subvolume create ./nocow
chattr +C nocow
```

However, I cannot find a way to show the C attr of the ./nocow. `lsattr` show empty result. This is probably because it only works on file/dir. I tried `btrfs property` But there is no way to show the attr of the subvolume so far. If I create a file in `./nocow` Then I can see it. But I want to list an empty subvolume's attr without create any files in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsattr ./nocow` where `nocow` is a directory is similar to `ls ./nocow` – both commands show the *contents* of the directory. You got an empty result because the directory is empty. It doesn't matter if the directory is a subvolume.

```
$ ls     ./nocow
$ lsattr ./nocow
$ touch  ./nocow/foo
$ ls     ./nocow
foo
$ lsattr ./nocow
---------------C------ ./nocow/foo
```

Like `ls -d`, `lsattr -d` shows the directory itself:

```bash
$ ls     -d ./nocow
./nocow
$ lsattr -d ./nocow
---------------C------ ./nocow
```